# How can I 'unfork' in GitHub Desktop?

Tags: github

I have forked a public Github repo using the Mac GitHub Desktop client, so I can make some changes and submit them.

I have got my fork into a total mess (I am not used to working with forks) and want to start over, but I cannot find a way to tell the client my repo should track the original repo rather than my fork... it seems irrevocably bound to my fork.

How can I get the client app to forget I *have* a fork?

Comment: if all else fails, xkcd has a solution: https://xkcd.com/1597/ :)

Answer (score 0):

I'll put up what I found by trial and error, but someone might have a better way:

I basically deleted my repo (form) on Github, and automagically the GitHub client showed my local repo now linked to the original repo again. I was able to go through the process of creating a fork all over again with my changes.